# Java HttpServer - ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: java, json, http, server

I am trying to make a webserver that uses a database to respond to certain queries introduced via the URI.

The problem that I have is related to the HTTP Handler. The Chrome returns ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH.

I followed the example from the Java documentation and theoretically it should work. IE and Edge do not display any error or text.

Could you please have a look and tell me if something is wrong?

Here is the code:

```
private class QueryHandler implements HttpHandler {

    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    private String result;
    private OutputStream os;

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        parameters = this.extractParameters(exchange.getRequestURI().getRawQuery());
        result = dbController.jsonQueryResponse(parameters.get("year"), parameters.get("day"), parameters.get("category")).toString();
        exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-32");
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, result.getBytes("UTF-32").length);
        os.write(result.getBytes("UTF-32"));
        exchange.close();
    }

    private Map<String, String> extractParameters(String query){
        Map<String, String> toBeReturned = new HashMap<>();

        for(String parameterValue : query.replaceFirst("\\?", "").split("&")){
            String[] parameter = parameterValue.split("=");
            toBeReturned.put(parameter[0], parameter[1]);
        }

        return toBeReturned;
    }
}
```

Interesting facts:

- Edge makes me download a txt file.
- IE does not.

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you see the ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH if the 2 browsers your mentioned dont display any error or text?

Comment: you seem to send a content-length of `result.length()` but this might differ from `result.getBytes().length` - depending on encoding and value of the result string, hence the mismatch error. So send `result.getBytes().length` as content-length instead.

Comment: @f1sh Please see edits.

Comment: @wero I already tried that and it does not work (I tried it one more time to be extra sure before writing it here).

Comment: @PetruDanielTudosiu at least this removes a possible source of error. You should also explicitly control the encoding by using `String.getBytes(CharSet)` and announce the encoding in the content-type header

Comment: @wero I made the suggested changes and I still have the same problem. Please see edits.

Comment: @PetruDanielTudosiu you still call `result.getBytes()`. Call `result.getBytes("UTF-32")` once and put it in a local variable and use it when setting the content-type and writing the output. I would also recommend to use UTF-8 instead, if there aren't special reasons to use UTF-32

Comment: @wero Did that, same error. I need the UTF 32 as I have some special chars in the return string.

Comment: UTF-8 can also handle 4 byte unicode characters (using variable length encoding). If you have less than 50% 4 byte characters use UTF-8 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found, I needed to set the content type to application/json.